# Share content (docs, video, etc) across other chapters outside salesforce app?

Tags: community, content

working on training documents (docs, video, webinars) and would like to share content to users across chapters. Thinking about creating a website for this purpose (ex. weebly.com) with password-protection and search function. Any idea on this to make the ease of content management sharing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share your files with any user may be not a salesforce user then you can upload files to chatter and generate a public link which could be shared over email.
[image]

Other solution could be create very less expensive chatter users and then share files when them by creating a chatter group.